# Not able to ping a docker container running with --net host from another container which runs on a n/w say net1

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I have multiple containers(total 6) running on network ***net1*** and only 1 container which runs with ***--net host*** flag.

One of the multiple containers is 'RestAPI container'....
and the one which runs with ***--net host*** is 'Protocol Container'

When I start the containers for the first time with fresh environment (removing all volumes... and containers) I am able to ping the Protocol container from RestAPI container.
When I restart the host machine(Ubuntu 20.04) I observe that the RestAPI container is able to ping other containers in its n/w but not able to ping the Protocol container.

I don't use docker compose I have written a shell script to run the containers.

Comment: I don't know why you can ping on the first try. However, you can [attach a container to multiple network](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#:~:text=When%20a%20container%20starts%2C%20it%20can%20only%20attach%20to%20a%20single%20network%2C%20using%20the%20%2D%2Dnetwork%20flag.%20You%20can%20connect%20a%20running%20container%20to%20multiple%20networks%20using%20the%20docker%20network%20connect%20command.)

Comment: @Max..... thanks for the response. 
However I found the cause of the issue.
It was regarding an SSL connection not properly verified in the RestAPI container. However I am yet to find a solution as to why this happens after a host restart. :)